# Speed up DynamoDBScanExpression searching

Tags: android, performance, listview, amazon-dynamodb

In my Android app I have a class that scans DynamoDB table and returns the results in a ListView.

CatalogActivity.java:

```
private class Scan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mpd = new ProgressDialog(CatalogActivity.this);
        mpd.setTitle(HomeActivity.name);
        mpd.setMessage("Searching for items...");
        mpd.setIndeterminate(false);
        mpd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        Condition condition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS)
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(HomeActivity.id));
        scanExpression.addFilterCondition("productId", condition);

        result = HomeActivity.mapper.scan(Product.class, scanExpression);
        arraylist = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for (Product prod : result) {
            prod.setName(prod.getName());
            prod.setPrice(prod.getPrice());
            prod.setProductId(prod.getProductId());
            prod.setSummary(prod.getSummary());
            prod.setSale(prod.getSale());
            prod.setSalePrice(prod.getSalePrice());
            arraylist.add(prod);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemsListView);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(CatalogActivity.this, arraylist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        mpd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Product> result = null;
private ArrayList<Product> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Product> result) {
    mContext = context;
    this.result = result;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Product>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(result);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemPrice;
    ImageView itemImage;
}

// Other required methods...

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_items, null);

        holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNameList);
        holder.itemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemPriceList);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImageList);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.itemName.setText(result.get(position).getName());
    holder.itemPrice.setText(Integer.toString(result.get(position).getPrice()) + "$");
    productId = result.get(position).getProductId();
    productSale = result.get(position).getSale();
    productSummary = result.get(position).getSummary();
```

As you can see, `CatalogActivity` scan the DynamoDB table and return its results, by sending the results to `ListViewAdapter`. `ListViewAdapter` takes the results, and enters them into a ListView in a predefined cell layout.

What's the problem? At the `onPreExecute` method in `CatalogActivity` I've set a Progress Dialog to show. At the `onPostExecute` method, I've dismissed this dialog. The problem is that the dialog is being dismissed after a few seconds, but the ListView cells only show after about half or full minute.

Is there any way to speed up the scanning and to apply cells faster?

Comment: What is the total number of records scan returns? and what is read throughput set on your table?

Comment: I have about 12 records in the table, but this is subject to change. About the read throughput do you mean to provisioned read capacity or something like that?

Comment: Because if so, then I have 10

Comment: This can also be caused by latency between your device/server and DynamoDB region

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the time of it? My DynamoDB table is on North Virginia and I'm in the Middle East. Do you think it's related?

Comment: Yes, it can be the reason but still it's not concrete, I am not an android developer but are you directly calling dynamodb from an android app or there is a server which will process the DB.?

Comment: @HarshalBulsara I'm calling it directly from DynamoDB.